# How to lock source code of terminal ran perl, obj c, c++, python, and ruby etc scripts?

Tags: python, linux, perl, terminal

I am looking to sell scripts I made in perl, obj c, c++, python, ruby, bash, php, etc etc etc

They are all ran in the terminal. (Linux)

How can I lock the source code, so my scripts can be distributed without people having access to the source codes..?

In other words, how do you lock the Source Code of a program that is run in Terminal, in so that people can use the program, if the code is downloaded onto their Linux machine, but the actual source code is not accessible to them?

Example:
example.pl is a document saved on the Linux Computer, and can be activated with Terminal. But if the user clicks on the actual example.pl document, they can see the actual code. Is it possible to lock this document, but still allow the user to run the program within terminal?

Comment: Did you consider releasing your software with a free license like GPLv3? You'll then sell support, not licenses!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not. If the computer can read it, the user can read it. The best you can do is *obfuscation* — you can look it up for your particular language, but there's no such thing as perfect obfuscation, either. Just take out all the spaces, change all your identifiers to single letters, and put a license on it.

Comment: I thought that obfuscation is not the only method, I have experience with backtrack 5, and as far as I know the terminal based programs can have the source code locked, such as sqlmap.py

Comment: @henrymb67 Nope. minitech is completely correct: if the computer can read it, so can your users. Digital Restrictions Management is mathematically impossible.

Comment: @Kirk Strauser So basically every application in the world you can see the source code of because your computer runs it? I find this hard to believe.

Comment: @henrymb67, No, not the source code. You won't get back comments and formatting, for example. You can generate source code for any program in the world, though.

Comment: For scripting languages, obfuscation is the best you can do. For compiled languages (e.g. C++, Objective-C), you'd typically distribute binaries if you don't want your users to read the source code. Some languages (e.g. Python) can also be compiled to bytecode, which isn't really human-readable either.

Comment: @omz, That's not true. You could compile any script language if you wanted to.

Comment: @ikegami: bash? That defeats the point of using a bash script.

Comment: @henrymb67 Obj C and C++? Sure. You end up with the compiled machine language object code. But even then, you can decompile those symbols back to something mostly human-readable. If that's possible with something as inherently obfuscated as C that's been run through an optimizing compiler, it's nearly trivial with any Perl/Python/Ruby/Bash/PHP obfuscation. If you doubt me, consider that almost all commercial apps are available, cracked, on the Internet. And I meant what I said: on a mathematical level, what you're hoping for just isn't possible.

Comment: @minitech, Sure, bash. I'm not saying you'd *want* to, or that the tools exist for all/any scripting language.

Comment: So what would be my best bet to hide the source from human readability?

Comment: @henrymb67: Like I said, minor obfuscation. Use an existing obfuscator so it's all convenient and automated. There's no point expending more effort to obfuscate the script than it would take to unobfuscate it.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: don't bother. This is effectively impossible on a technical level. Instead, have a lawyer draw up a good software license that prevents clients from redistributing your code and have them sign it as part of your sales contract.

Then weep when your client's nephew in college realizes that your app is a Perl script, writes a drop-in replacement, and releases it on Github for free.

Sad, but true. There's no way I'd try to build a business around selling easily-cloned software today. Think of how many nearly identical apps there are on the iTunes App Store for example, and (presumably) none of those developers ever got to see their competitors' code.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to distribute your program without distributing the source code. But that doesn't achieve anything. The user can regenerate equivalent source code, allowing him to copy parts of your code, use parts of your code or find out exactly what your code does. I'm sure one or all of those is your actual goal.

Comment: Thank you so much ikegami!!, ... how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Do what? I already explained it doesn't achieve any of your goals.

Comment: ah yes... didnt realize it still doesn't achieve anything.